# request.POST['time'] must be a datefield()

Tags: python, django

I'm very new to django, maybe I'm asking something very elemental.

I have the following code :

```
crush.time = request.POST['time']
```

this 'time' post value is a timefield and I need to process as a time value, but all I got is that crush.time is a string, and then I got the following error when I try to process:

```
'unicode' object has no attribute 'hour'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the Python `datetime` library to convert to a time object:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(request.POST['time'], '%H:%M:%S').time()
```

Answer (score 1):

The POST multidictionary contains strings - it does not know about python data types. You have to parse it into a datetime object. look at the datetime documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your '*time*' field is in the form H:M:S or H:M, then you could create a django form to do the parsing work for you (keep in mind you don't necessarily need to output the form):

In your forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class BasicTimeForm(forms.Form):
    time = forms.TimeField()
```

In your view:

```
if request.method == 'POST': 
    form = forms.BasicTimeForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        crush.time = form.cleaned_data['time']
```

After a post, *crush.time* should now contain a datetime.time.

(adapted from http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)

Comment: there is no other way to do not use this class implemetation? I only want to parse this string into a datetime object.. it looks like a lot of work for parsing a simple object.

Comment: You can simplify things a little by using a ModelForm instead of a regular Form (see the django documentation).  And you should be doing the form validation anyway rather than directly setting `crush.time = request.POST['time']` because some users will inevitably make mistakes entering the time into your form, and if you don't handle it right they'll just see a 500 error.